# Rails sphinx search undefined method `stringify_keys!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I try to search in my mysql database using thinking_sphinx gem. But I am having some troubles:

I get the error:

```
1.9.3-p429 :002 > Article.search "diesel"

**NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "diesel":String**

    from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/meta_search-1.1.3/lib/meta_search/builder.rb:86:in `build'
    from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/meta_search-1.1.3/lib/meta_search/searches/active_record.rb:43:in `metasearch'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

my `app/indices/article_index.rb`:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :article, :with => :active_record do
  indexes :ART_ARTICLE_NR
end
```

(also, I have non standard db, field is uppercase)

gemfile:

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx'
gem 'mysql2'
```

Why am I getting this error?

Also when I try:

```
1.9.3-p429 :003 >  Article.search(ART_ARTICLE_NR: "diesel")
```

I get:

```
Killed
```

I have sphinx 2.0.4.

Comment: Do you use MetaSearch gem as well?

Comment: @IlyaKhokhryakov No, just have it in gemfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace you see that actually MetaSearch gives an error, not ThinkingSphinx. The issue is that both gems add `search` method to `ActiveRecord::Base` and you get a name conflict. Actually you call `search` method that belongs to MetaSearch and requires quite different params. To get rid of the name conflict, add `thinking-sphinx` below `meta_search` in Gemfile. After this you would be able to use `Article.search` to run ThinkingSphinx search and `Article.metasearch` to run MetaSearch one without errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you also use `meta_search` gem. Looks like it also adds `search` method in your models, which is redefined equally named method of `thinking_sphinx`

The solution is not to use `meta_search`, for example.